# Netplan - how to bring wifi interface up only?

Tags: 20.04, netplan, focus

On Focal ubuntu server, I just want the wifi interface to come up without trying to connect. I take my laptop to several coffee shops so it would not make sense to hard code the values here. Instead, I will use wpa_supplicant.

Right now the interface comes up but it tries to connect to the internet and timesout after 2 minutes. How can I make just the wifi interface come up without trying to connect? Also, would the only way be to decrease the timeout limit?

```
localhost# cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml 
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enxa0cec83b0910:
      dhcp4: true
  wifis:
    wlp58s0:
      access-points:
        opennetwork: {}
      dhcp4: false
```

Comment: 20.04 focal .... running ubuntu server

Comment: Did you install a Desktop Environment onto your install of Ubuntu Server 20.04? Or are you logging into a TTY and running everything from shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your `wifis.wlp58s0` interface to be `optional: true`, that should avoid the timeout. (https://netplan.io/reference/#common-properties-for-all-device-types)